# Angular 2 Reactive Forms issue how to do in angular way not jquery way

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I use Angular 2 Reactive Forms with Typescript.
I have a template like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="M">
        <div class="X">
            <!-- I dont want to put (change)="onChanged()" on every inputs-->
            <input class="A" formControlName="MXA" /> 
            <input class="B"  formControlName="MXB" />
            <input class="C" formControlName="MXC" />
        </div>
        <div class="Y">
            <input class="A" formControlName="MYA" />
            <input class="B" formControlName="MYB" />
            <input class="C" formControlName="MYC" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="N">
        <div class="X">
            <input class="A" formControlName="NXA" />
            <input class="B" formControlName="NXB" />
            <input class="C" formControlName="NXC" />
        </div>
        <div class="Y">
            <input class="A" formControlName="NYA" />
            <input class="B" formControlName="NYB" />
            <input class="C" formControlName="NYC" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the component class:

```
export class MyCompoenent {

  public form: FormGroup;

  onInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      MXA: new FormControl(),
      MXB: new FormControl(),
      MXC: new FormControl(),
      MYA: new FormControl(),
      MYB: new FormControl(),
      MYC: new FormControl(),
      NXA: new FormControl(),
      NXB: new FormControl(),
      NXC: new FormControl(),
      NYA: new FormControl(),
      NYB: new FormControl(),
      NYC: new FormControl(),
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((p) => {
      /* I dont't know which input has been changed here */
    });
    this.form.get('MXA').valueChanges.subscribe((p) => {
      /* I dont't want to subscribe to every individual input like this, its not good solution when there is too many inputs */
    });

  }

}
```

What I want is:

**1. There are four div of three inputs, the 3 inputs have a relationship A+B=C, whenever one of the input change, it should check in the same div if another input has value, if it has, then calculate the third input.**

e.g. the value of the input M => X => A is 2, then the user enter 3 in M => X => B, then the M => X => C is set automatically to 5

**2. If a input change, it should update another input which has the same class in the SAME grand parent div.**

e.g. the value of the input M => X => A is set to 5, then should set 5 to the input M => Y => A

Thiking in jquery way it is easy because I can do a single bind to all inputs and I can know which input trigger the change event, then I can navigate in the DOM from the triggered input.

But I want know how to do it properly in Angular way. 
this.form.valueChanges() don't show which input has been changed, and **I don't like to subscribe each input separately, don't like to put some bindings in every input in the angular template**, because if there are too many inputs I need to do many work, and not want to use something like getElementsByClassName which is "jquery way", any idea ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can define ***formControlName*** in every single input and then check them when any of them change.The value of formControl you can probably get like that

```
this.form.get("formControleName");
```

or you can define formControle and then subscribe to that

```
filterName = new FormControl(null);
constructor(){
  this.filterName.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (value) 
  }
}
```

There is other option but I will not recommend it.

```
  <input #inputAX (change)="aChanged(inputBX)"/> 
  <input #inputBX (change)="bChanged(inputAX)"/>
```

and then check if element has value

```
  aChanged(element) {
  if(element.value)
  }

  bChanged(element) {
  if(element.value)
  }
```

Comment: Yes I have formControlName in every single input, how you subscribe the value changes and how to know which input is changed ?